# "invalid_grant" error when accessing https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only from a Service Account

Tags: rest, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

We recently started using Google Cloud Platform. There is a bucket for which we want to retrieve data from.

However, there is a problem in authenticating and getting the token which we can later use to issue HTTP requests at the Cloud Storage API.

I believe the scope we are using for that is the right one: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only [as described in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication ]

We followed the guide from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#serviceaccount to set-up a Service account, create a JWT, sign it, **POST** it and feed all the required details in our application(email, private key, scope). Then the following error occurs(right after the POST request):

**16:18:15: 1response(oauth2):**

**16:18:15: 1Error code     400**

**16:18:15: 1Error message  Bad Request**

**16:18:15: 1Error response { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request"}**

**16:18:15: %%% oauth2 400 Bad Request**

We can retrieve the same data we want with the Playground app(https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) and gsutil from a specific bucket.

Note: The same code we are using to issue the **POST** works 100% fine when accessing the Google BigQuery API and authenticating with the BigQuery Scope in a different project in the Google Developers Console.

I am aware that a **400 HTTP** error means invalid format, but since the same request is already working with BigQuery API but not with the Google Cloud Storage API(only difference is the scope/endpoint supplied), does anyone know what might be causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? For me, Google sign in works on Android and not on iOS.